# <g:resource> <r:layoutResources> unknown tags in grails project ?Also features of bootstrap are not rendered in .gsp file. What's the solution?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, plugins

I have installed twitter bootstrap plugin in `buildConfig.groovy` file, but none of the bootstrap features seem to be rendered in my .gsp files. Also, when I try to use tags like `<g:render>`, `<g:each>` , `<g:resource>` anything, it shows me an error saying unknown tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Perkin Elmer Support</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" />
<!-- appears as unknown tag and also none of <g:..> tags work !-->

    <asset:stylesheet src="../stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="../stylesheets/bootstrap.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="../stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="../stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="../stylesheets/application.css"/>
    <asset:javascript src="../javascripts/application.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="../javascripts/bootstrap.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="../javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"/>
</head>
```

In buildConfig.groovy also i have installed the plugin.

```
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.3" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.15"
runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.1.1.3'
```

How do I link to bootstrap files in my gsp page ?
And I can't use any of `<g:resource>` `<g:render>` , `<g:..>` tags inside my .gsp file ?

Comment: I can't use any of <g:resource>, <g:render>, etc any such tags in my .gsp file

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are asking

Comment: @vefthym   1) I have installed twitter bootstrap plugin in buildConfig.groovy file but none of the bootstrap features seem to be rendered in my .gsp files.                                                                   2) When I try to use tags like <g:render>, <g:each> , <g:resource> anything, it shows me an error saying unknown tag. Can you tell me what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could use the [Asset Pipeline Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline).

When you save your file in **grails-app/assets/stylesheets**, the code boils down to

```
<asset:stylesheet src="main.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The g:resource tag is not working as you expect because you are not using it correctly. According to the [grails documentation of the resource tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html) `<g:resource />` only creates the path to a file. eg:

```
<g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" />
```

will generate: "/*appName*/css/main.css"

To make it link as a stylesheet you will need to use the tag's method form inside of an html link tag:

```
<link type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" />
```

which results in: <link type="text/css" href="/*appName*/css/main.css" />